# ExtendedFloatingActionButton without using MaterialComponentTheme

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I want to use ExtendedFloatingActionButton but I don't want to apply activity wide MaterialComponent themes because I have existing buttons with custom backgrounds and icons and I'll need to modify those for material themes. 
I tried using MaterialComponent Bridge themes but ExtendedFloatingActionButton doesn't work with bridge theme. It's not rendered properly.

Comment: It's time to switch to the Material Component Theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by explicitly applying style to the ExtendedFloatingActionButton while using the bridge theme for activity.

```
<activity
      android:name=".ui.activity.ActivityName"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/AppThemeMaterial.NoActionBar">
```

while AppTheme material is

```
<style name="AppThemeMaterial" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge" />
```

You can use any of the bridge themes. Finally, applied the ExtendedFloatingActionButton theme explicitly.

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
         android:id="@+id/fab"
         style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
         ... 
/>
```